# XML file from google spreadsheet cell

Tags: xml

im looking for resolution to save a values from cell to xml file in google drive. i trying write a macro but i dont know how i declarat name of file, destination, and XML file.

```
function xmlDSADV() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var file =  ss.getSheetByName("DSADV").getRange('A1').getValues();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " DSADV " + formattedDate;
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1iuS2Ae4HamRYoXOoRGS6IGvlhlRxH_i9");
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(file)
    file.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
    Logger.log(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a resolution:

````
function xmlDSADV() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var xmlstring = ss.getSheetByName("DSADV").getRange('A1').getDisplayValues();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " DSADV " + formattedDate + ".xml";
DriveApp.getFolderById("1iuS2Ae4HamRYoXOoRGS6IGvlhlRxH_i9").createFile(name, xmlstring)


}
```
````